# Can't enable Identity Platform on Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Nothing happens when I click the "Enable Identity Platform" on Google Cloud Console. What do I need to do?

[image: Enable Cloud Platform]

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it. So the issue might have something to do with having multiple google accounts. I tried copy and pasting the link of the button into the browser address bar and was brought to identity platform page for my main google account (showing  message of failing to create identity provider). I then switched to the account I wanted to add the identity provider by clicking on the top-right menu. I got brought back to the page with the button "Enable Identity Platform" and this time when I clicked it, I got brought to the identity platform page for the right google account and I could continue.